# Build output of SpiderMonkey under Windows

Tags: firefox, spidermonkey

I built SpiderMonkey 60 under Windows (VS2017) according to the [documentation](https://github.com/TheQwertiest/foo_spider_monkey_panel/wiki/Building-SpiderMonkey), using
`../configure --enable-nspr-build` followed by `mozmake`.
In the output folder (dist\bin) I could see 5 DLLs created:

`mozglue.dll, mozjs-60.dll, nspr4.dll, plc4.dll, plds4.dll`

In order to run the SpiderMonkey [Hello World sample](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/How_to_embed_the_JavaScript_engine) I linked my C++ program with mozjs-60.lib and had to copy over to my program location the following DLLs: `mozglue.dll, mozjs-60.dll, nspr4.dll`

It seems that `plc4.dll, plds4.dll` are not needed for the program to run and execute scripts. 
I could not find any documentation about what is the purpose of each one of the DLLs. Do I need all 5 DLLs? what is the purpose of each one?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [NSPR archived release notes for an old version](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/nspr/release-notes/nspr462) I found this:

> The plc (Portable Library C) library is a separate library from the
>   core nspr. You do not need to use plc if you just want to use the core
>   nspr functions. The plc library currently contains thread-safe string
>   functions and functions for processing command-line options.
>
> The plds (Portable Library Data Structures) library supports data
>   structures such as arenas and hash tables. It is important to note
>   that services of plds are not thread-safe. To use these services in a
>   multi-threaded environment, clients have to implement their own
>   thread-safe access, by acquiring locks/monitors, for example.

It sounds like they are unused unless specifically loaded by your application.

It seems it would be safe to not distribute these if you don't need them.

Comment: ps I could not find any specific linkage to plc4 in the spidermonkey source (grep for plc4 in v74 only hits in the nspr tree)